# Google Sheets Filter and Replace Array

Tags: arrays, lambda, vlookup, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that contains a list of tables from a SQL Server and for each table, their respective column data types. I am looking for a way to output a standard value for each data type in the order it is received.

Hopefully this isn't too confusing, essentially instead of outputting results from filter, I want to run them through one more formula to replace the filtered value with a new value. I just can't seem to figure out a short method and keeping it an array.

[Sheet - Filter & Repalce](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C3jFXk1vb47OG1vBM_mod0LAGIYpbI66eTx3T09TYGE/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: sadly its confusing coz your dataset example does not contain how should be what replaced. edit your sheet and include example of desired result that can be actually reproduced/solved

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I want to take my current formula that joins an array of `DATA_TYPE` for each table and replace them with generic values. Like anytime `nvarchar` appears, it instead outputs `"abc"` (with quotes), `int` is replaced by `99`. Does that help? There are about 10 different data types in total spanning hundreds of rows for different tables. I just want to insert generic data depending on the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(FILTER(H2:H, H2:H<>""), LAMBDA(x, JOIN(", ", 
 INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(G:G, C:C=x, F:F="NO"), 
 {"nvarchar","""abc""" ; "int",99}, 2, ), 
 FILTER(G:G, C:C=x, F:F="NO")))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I was not aware of `LAMBDA`